# Get Current URL, With Modified Parameters

Tags: url, geturl, parameter

#### Problem

I'm trying to come up with a consistent way to get the current URL of the page, including parameters from both the `key/value/key/value` structure and the `?key=value&key=value` structure.

#### What I've tried

The simplest method that I've found works like this:

```
$params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
$params = array_merge($params, $newParams);
$url = $this->getUrl('*/*/*', $params);
```

However, this doesn't escape parameter values at all. So I do that myself like this:

```
$params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
$params = array_merge($params, $newParams);

foreach ($params as $k => &$v) {
    $v= urlencode($v);
}

$url = $this->getUrl('*/*/*', $params);
```

Okay great, now I have encoded parameters. But what if the parameters include the `/` character? You end up with a URL like this: `my_module/my_controller/my_action/FromEntryDate/12%2F06%2F2014/ToEntryDate/06%2F04%2F2015/`

But if you do `Zend_Debug::dump($this->getRequest());` you get this:

```
array(5) {
  ["FromEntryDate"] => string(2) "12"
  ["06"] => string(4) "2014"
  ["ToEntryDate"] => string(2) "06"
  ["04"] => string(4) "2015"
}
```

So clearly the `/` aren't being interpreted correctly, even though they are encoded. So I end up with this work around instead:

```
$r = $this->getRequest();

$params = $r->getParams();
$params = array_merge($params, $newParams);

$url = implode('/', array(
    $r->getBaseUrl(),
    $r->getRouteName(),
    $r->getControllerName(),
    $r->getActionName()
)).'?'.http_build_query($params);
```

#### Questions

1. Is there no way to encode `/` characters so that Magento will parse the param value correctly?
2. Is there not a built in function to do this already!?